# How to plot point by point in a for loop?

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation

I first apologize for my english which is still approximative and for the spelling, I hope all will be clear.

My problem is the following:

- I need to first solve a non-linear implicit 2-dimensional equation. I did that by using FindRoot and the results I obtained seem to be good. I have to solve this equation with respect to different parameters, here wee and wii, hence I did a loop over those two.
- Then I compute a matrix that I can now calculate using the solutions I got from `FindRoot`. What interests me in this matrix is the sign of its trace and its determinant, I want to find the area in the parameter space (wee,wii) where I have a negative trace and a positive determinant. So what I would like to do (and obviously what I didn't succeed in implementing so far...) is to plot a point of coordinates (wee,wii) if these two inequalities are verified.

Here my actual code :

```
For[wee = 0, wee <= 1, wee = wee + 1,
For[wii = 0, wii <= 2, wii = wii + 1, 

hcurrente[x_, y_] := wee*x - wei*y;
hcurrenti[x_, y_] := wie*x - wii*y;

sol = FindRoot[{-alphae*x + (1 - x)*F[hcurrente[x, y]] == 
  0, -alphai*y + (1 - y)*F[hcurrenti[x, y]] == 0}, {{x, 0.7}, {y, 
  0.7}}, MaxIterations -> 100];

xp = x /. sol;
yp = y /. sol;

matA0 = {{(1 - xp)*wee*F'[hcurrente[xp, yp]] - alphae - 
  F[hcurrente[xp, yp]], (1 - yp)*F'[hcurrenti[xp, yp]]*
  wie}, {-(1 - xp)*F'[hcurrente[xp, yp]]*
  wei, -(1 - yp)*F'[hcurrenti[xp, yp]]*wii - alphai - 
  F[hcurrenti[xp, yp]]}};

Tm = Tr[matA0];
Dm = Det[matA0];

ineq = Tm < 0 && Dm > 0;

If[ineq, Graphics[Point[{wee, wii}], Axes -> True]]
]]
```

I think this question has been already treated therefore I have been many times in the forum to find a way but in vain. For example, I already tried to use, `Reap`, `Sow`, etc.. but I always had a problem (compilation error, no plot, ...). I am now a bit out of time.

Comment: Your code is incomplete and can't be executed, so it is impossible for anyone to experiment with it and find out what is wrong and make corrections. Please provide _complete_ code.

Comment: A For-loop always returns `Null` and therefore makes no visible output. If you want to plot the points you are computing, you must gather them up into a list within your For-loops and make the plot from the list outside of the For-loop.

Comment: You have parameters wei and wie that are not defined.

Comment: Not "the MMA way", but start simple and work up from there: goodpoints={}; For[wee=0, wee<=1, wee=wee+1, For[wii=0, wii<=2, wii=wii+1, ineq=True; If[ineq, goodpoints = Append[goodpoints, Point[{wee, wii}]] ]]]; Show[Graphics[goodpoints]]

Comment: The top of my code is just the variables declaration and of the function F.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This started out as a comment but got a bit long...

You're not approaching this in the "*Mathematica* way".  I suggest defining a function of `wee` and `wii` which uses `FindRoot` to give your matrix, e.g.

```
myMatrix[wee_, wii_] := Module[{hcurrente, hcurrenti, sol, xp, yp},
    hcurrente[x_, y_] := wee*x - wei*y;
    hcurrenti[x_, y_] := wie*x - wii*y;

    sol = FindRoot[{-alphae*x + (1 - x)*F[hcurrente[x, y]] == 
      0, -alphai*y + (1 - y)*F[hcurrenti[x, y]] == 0}, {{x, 0.7}, {y, 
      0.7}}, MaxIterations -> 100];

    xp = x /. sol;
    yp = y /. sol;

    {{(1 - xp)*wee*F'[hcurrente[xp, yp]] - alphae - 
      F[hcurrente[xp, yp]], (1 - yp)*F'[hcurrenti[xp, yp]]*
      wie}, {-(1 - xp)*F'[hcurrente[xp, yp]]*
      wei, -(1 - yp)*F'[hcurrenti[xp, yp]]*wii - alphai - 
      F[hcurrenti[xp, yp]]}}
]
```

(Note this is by necessity entirely untested and unsimplified, I have simply copied and pasted some of the code from inside the `For` loops in your question directly into this answer.)

Then you can map your expression involving the trace and determinant using a suitable plotting function, e.g.

```
RegionPlot[Module[{m = myMatrix[wee, wii]}, Tr[m] < 0 && Det[m] > 0],
    {wee, 0, 1}, {wii, 0, 2}]]
```

Or use other functions such as `FindMinimum` to find optimal points in your parameter space (without resorting to using `For` loops!).